# Save data in two persistent stores

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, magicalrecord

I am having an app where there is a search feature that does a network request. However uses the same model framework as the entire app.

This means that when the user searches for something I need to create managed objects from the found data, save them and display them. However this messes up old records with the user recent data.

I would ideally like to save the managed objects found in the search in a separate in-memory persistent store so it doesn't make disorder in the main data.

I haven't done something like this before so what is the best way to approach it?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want it only in-memory but optionally saved, you could have the search results as part of a child *context*.   And have the GUI interact with the child context with the option to save or discarding the data in the child context.  Judging from what you wrote, you don't actually want a persistent store of the search results-- they do not need to be retained if the app is killed or quit-- do clarify if so.  [Good article on multi-context here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/).  A classic use is a form that has a cancel button to discard the whole child store.

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested by @stevesliva, you do not need to involve yourself into the complexities of maintaining multiple partially in-memory stores. The way to go here is to create a *child context* and fetch the online data into this context. Once you do not need the data any more, just discard the context.

If you decide to save the downloaded data, you can simply "push" the changes to the main context via `save:`. At that point you could make necessary adjustments to the data so they fit into the user data. Depending on your model, one feasible solution could be to create another attribute on one of the entities that marks linked objects as distinct from the user created objects.